# ContentPlaceHolder with link in master page and default.aspx page

Tags: asp.net, css, stylesheet, hyperlink, master-pages

I am using

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link id="Link2" href="~/App_Shared/CSS/AjaxStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

this code in master page and in default.aspx page we have its content div like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Now i want to add a new style sheet css file in this content div at default.aspx page like the master page. and in this link href i will give the relative URL (use ~ sign URL)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server">
    <link id="Link1" href="~/App_Shared/CSS/DefaultStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

but when it runs it displays me on HTML page source

```
<link id="Link2" href="../App_Shared/CSS/AjaxStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and

```
<link id="Link1" href="~/App_Shared/CSS/DefaultStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How to resolve this second one link id="Link1" like the first one id="Link2".
I want link1 href converted into a absolute path like link2...
but how????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add stylesheet by using c# code like this...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
        css.Href = "css/fancyforms.css";
        css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
        css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
        css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
}
```

I hope it works as per your requirement...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue when trying to link in javascript files manually. Try the following in default.aspx :

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>App_Shared/CSS/DefaultStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As a sidenote, you only end this tag with "/>" if you are using a xhtml doctype, above example is for html.